# Connect phonegap app to a server

Tags: javascript, mysql, cordova, server

I have a Phonegap App where I mainly have some forms to fill for the clients. After having the information, I want to send this to a server where I have my database and add this clients to my database.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: So mainly I have now an object "client" with informations and I want to send this to the ERP server which is developed in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use normal [HTML forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) or then dynamic [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) ([W3 tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) & [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)) to submit the data to the server. On server side you of course need to be able to handle these HTTP requests properly and put the data in the database.

Here's example about both cases. They should do about the same thing.

HTML form (modified from W3 tutorial)

```
<form action="www.example.com/form_page.php" method="POST">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="first-name" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="last-name" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

which makes a call on a script form_page.php at server *www.example.com*.

AJAX with jQuery (modified from jQuery documentation)

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "www.example.com/form_page.php",
  data: {
    firstName: jQuery("#first-name").val(), 
    lastName: jQuery("#last-name").val()
  }
}).done(function(msg) { // This is called when request is done
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! The thing is that there are more than one form. So, i have 3 pages, with 3 different forms which depends if the client is private or business. After this forms, I have all the information in an object "client" filled. How can I send this info to the server and how I make this connection?